# SQL query for all unique values for a particular ID

Tags: sql

I am very new to SQL so wanted to check on the forums here...
Am trying to query the following dataset:

```
Customer ID Item Purchased
1234            Bread
1235            Peanut Butter
1234            Jelly
1234            Peanut Butter
1234            Jelly
5555            Peanut Butter
5555            Peanut Butter
1235            Jelly
```

I'm trying to get the expected result of:

```
Customer ID Item Purchased
1234            Bread
1234            Jelly
1234            Peanut Butter
5555            Peanut Butter
1235            Jelly
1235            Peanut Butter
```

Please help me:) thanks!

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY` or `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: . . Ask another question.  What you describe in the comment is definitely not the question you asked.  If you change the question, you will invalidate the people who tried to help you by answering this question -- and that can draw downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

use `SELECT DISTINCT` to select all the unique rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use below query might be it will help, don't forget to change table name and column name

```
  Select distinct Customer_ID, Item_Purchased 
  from YourTableName
```

Comment: for clarification is there a is only clause I can use. So I want to query to find out which customer is only buying Bread for example?